# Dynamic product list page php

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

kinda new here. My question is about displaying dyamically product data from database in one row 4 different products side by side not in one column

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-3">
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
      $select_all_products_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_products_query)) {
      $product_sku = $row['Product_sku'];
      $product_name = $row['Product_name'];
      $product_price = $row['Product_price'];

      ?>
        <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="sku"><a><?php echo $product_sku ?></a></h3>
                <h2 class="name"><a><?php echo $product_name ?></a></h2>
                <h2 class="price"><a><?php echo $product_price ?></a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I understand from your question. Try this one.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th><?php echo $product_sku ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $product_name ?></th> 
    <th><?php echo $product_price ?></th>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```